# Counting rocks of different sizes on shoreline using ArcGIS Desktop?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, geotiff-tiff, digital-image-processing

I have a 5cm resolution geotiff image for a shoreline. I need to count the number of rocks in three classes (e.g., >6 feet, 3-6 feet, and <3 feet). I don't have any point cloud data.

What will be the best gis approach to solve this problem?

[image]

Comment: A "geotiff image" could be anything! It could be a 3-band RGB image, a DEM, some calculated index, etc. Please specify what your image data are. Even better, provide a picture.

Comment: when you said this: `>6 feet, 3-6 feet, and <6 feet`
did you mean this: `>6 feet, 3-6 feet, and <3 feet` ?

Comment: Of what? A raster of what? Binary image of rocks? DEM? What do the raster values represent? Please post an image.

Comment: sorry it should be <3 feet.

Comment: @Jon I added a picture

Comment: @Javed Ok, there is no way that's a 1 band 8 bit raster. Also, I don't think this is a great question for GIS because it's really image processing. You won't need to use any GIS techniques to solve it (unless you want the georeferenced coordinates of each rock). Also, it looks pretty difficult. You'll need edge detection/object identification of some kind. The trees and the algae aren't doing you any favors, either. If you're just doing this image, you can do it by hand by tracing either rock boundaries or major axes, then GIS would be useful.

Comment: @Jon You're right about the data. It should be a RGB. I exported it from global mapper and it was showing 1 band in ArcMap. I guess there is no easy way around then.

Comment: @Javed You should state in your question what kind of solution you're looking for. Do you just want help creating a shapefile layer that you can hand-draw rock polygons into, or are you looking for an algorithmic approach? If it's the latter, I don't think you're gonna get much from this site.

Comment: @Jon I was just wondering if there is a better solution out there. I thought about object oriented image classification but I don't think it is gonna identify each different sizes as all the rocks will have same spectral signatures. What I am currently doing is, I created a grid of 3x3 feet cells and three point feature classes. I am going through each grid and kind of hand picking each rock. But it's a tedious process. I am just going to interpolate at some point. All I need though is a rough estimate.

Comment: I haven't messed with it but have seen promising demonstrations for object detection and inventorying.  ArcGIS Pro has [machine learning](https://www.esri.com/arcgis-blog/products/arcgis-pro/analytics/machine-learning-in-arcgis/) capabilities.  If Pro isn't available, there are [open source machine learning projects](https://www.tensorflow.org/) out there.

Comment: I suggest you ask in the imagej forum https://forum.image.sc/
The imagej is used to identify shapes, size, colors, etc. in microscope images, I believe someone there can help you.

Comment: Since this seems pretty fuzzy, what with rocks being covered by others and other objects, you might want to approach this a rough pattern density problem. Botanists use pictures/transparencies of density to classify sections. There's certainly a way to use GIS to help with this.

Comment: I would use a deep learning approach for this object detection problem. Here is one approach: https://devblogs.nvidia.com/detectnet-deep-neural-network-object-detection-digits/

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this is a purely image analysis question with no GIS relevance.

Answer (score 10):

For the most part not an ArcGIS answer but you could try it anyway since it is completely free software.

You could try using [scikit-image](http://scikit-image.org). You will get it if you install [Anaconda](https://anaconda.org/anaconda/python) (with Anaconda you also get jupyter-notebook which is a great python ide and lots of other useful python libraries).

I followed this tutorial, with very limited experience of image processing and got some results: [Region-based segmentation](http://scikit-image.org/docs/0.12.x/auto_examples/xx_applications/plot_coins_segmentation.html#region-based-segmentation)

```py
import skimage
import numpy as np
rocks = skimage.io.imread('/home/bera/Downloads/rocks.jpg')
rocks_greyscale = skimage.color.rgb2gray(rocks)

elevation_map = skimage.filters.sobel(rocks_greyscale)

markers = np.zeros_like(rocks_greyscale)
markers[rocks_greyscale < 0.3] = 1 #Adjust, I just tried different values
markers[rocks_greyscale > 0.7] = 2 #Adjust

segmentation = skimage.morphology.watershed(elevation_map, markers)

skimage.io.imsave('/home/bera/Downloads/rocks_segmented.tif',segmentation)
```

You will need some tweaking. Not all stones are segmented and some things that are not stones is. Then convert the output image to vector and use for example minimum bounding geometry to get size of stones. Or use some raster tool to count different size objects.

[image]

[image]

Comment: You could actually also estimate the height of (some of) the rocks if you could attach each rock's shadow segment to its segment. @Javed I wrote a python script to replace Matlab's regionprops if you make it this far. It provides statistics, coordinates, measurements, etc. on blobs (segments) in your image. It really just wraps around skimage, nothing too fancy. Shoot me a message if you get far along enough to need it.

Comment: @BERA How did you get the nice violet map from the white/black segmentation result?

Comment: I cant remember. Probably just by styling the black and white raster in QGIS