# Automated Object Boundary Detection in Raster Layers from LAS Point Cloud Classification in QGIS or Python

Tags: python, raster, software-recommendations, las, point-cloud

I have a `raster layer` generated from `LAS point cloud` classification, where pixel groups represent `objects` (e.g., rocks) detected above ground.

However, the classification is not perfect, and the objects appear united instead of being delineated individually. I'm looking for existing solutions or tools that can automatically draw boundaries around these pixel groups, either using QGIS or Python.

Instead of developing a new algorithm, I want to find established approaches or tools that can accomplish this task.

I have provided an example of the raster layer (on the left), and manually drawn boundaries on the right (not all boundaries are shown in the example).

I seek any recommendations or suggestions for existing solutions that can automate object boundary detection in raster layers.

Any relevant info on QGIS plugins, Python libraries, or other software that can help achieve this goal?

[image]

Comment: https://scikit-image.org/docs/dev/auto_examples/
https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/297035/counting-rocks-of-different-sizes-on-shoreline-using-arcgis-desktop/297042#297042